# pytorch: how to calculate the loss by for-loop

Tags: pytorch, loss

I want to calculate my-self loss. I want to predict N point by deep learning. Thus, the output of network is N point (N*3).
The numpy calculation should be:

```
import numpy as np

point1 = np.random.random(size=[10, 30, 3])
point2 = np.random.random(size=[10, 30, 3])

losses = []
for s in range(10):
    loss = 0
    for p in range(30):
        p1 = point1[s, p, :]
        dis = p1 - point2[s, :, :]
        dis = np.linalg.norm(dis, axis=1)
        loss += dis.min()
    losses.append(loss)
print(loss)
```

In pytorch, the point should be:

```
point1 = np.random.random(size=[10, 30, 3])
point2 = np.random.random(size=[10, 30, 3])

point1 = torch.from_numpy(point1)
point2 = torch.from_numpy(point2)
```

How can I calculate the loss in pytorch?

Any suggestion is appreciated！

Comment: Do you want to write your own custom loss function in pytorch?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to use for-loop in pytorch.

Comment: Well there is no separate for loop in pytorch, it is the same old for loop in python!

Comment: For computing `loss`, the only potential issue I see is the use of `loss +=` which could be replaced by `loss = loss +` to avoid inplace operations. I'm not actually sure if this is necessary since some inplace ops are supported by autograd now. The norm could be replaced by `torch.norm(dis, dim=1)`